# R function returning boolean of which element in vector is maximum

Tags: r

I need a boolean that tells me whether an element of a vector is that vector's maximum. Should return something like this

```
vec <- c(3,4,1,5)

maxBoolFunct(vec)

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

`max()` just tells me what the maximum value actually is and `which.max` simply gives me the position in the vector. I need a boolean.

Comment: `vec == max(vec)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use logical indexing.

```
> vec = c(3,4,1,5)
> vec == max(vec)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```